# Global media queries on a react project

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'm trying to generate a general structure of styles on scss with global breakpoints as media queries on a react project, It is possible to reuse an structure to follow media queries that we declare as global. 
I'm a little bit lost on this one, any ideas?

When I mean global is that we can define the breakpoints at the root of the project and we can use any reference on the components.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question needs more detail. When you say "global", do you mean to imply that you want to include the style at the top level of your app only, rather than declared component by component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways that come to mind:

1. You can create a `variables.scss` file in which you can write the value of your breakpoints:

`$sm: 576px;
$md: 768px;
$lg: 992px;
$xl: 1200px;`

And the use the following variables in your scss:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: $sm) {
    .container {
        .max-width: 450px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: $md) {
    .container {
        .max-width: 650px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: $lg) {
    .container {
        .max-width: 900px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: $xl) {
    .container {
        .max-width: 1000px;
    }
}
```

2. Or you can the mentioned variables in your `mixins.scss` file to create some media query mixins:

   `@mixin small {
       @media only screen and (min-width: $sm) {
           @content;
       }
   }`

And then, use these mixins in your main scss codes:

```
.container {
    @include small {
        max-width: 450px;
    }
    ...
}
```

3. Or if the use cases of these media queries are limited (e.g. hiding and showing elements), you can define other mixins that include all the variations:

   `$displays: none inline inline-block block table table-cell table-row flex inline-flex;
   $sizes: (
       sm: $sm,
       md: $md,
       lg: $lg,
       lg: $xl
   );
   @each $display in $displays:
       @each $size-key $size in $sizes {
           .display-#{size-key}-#{display} {
               display: $display !important;
           }
     }
   }`

**A note on importing files:** I personally would import all my helper scss (variables, mixins, etc.) in a file called `styles/index.scss` in the root of my project among with normalizing and other global rules that I want to define, and then import this file in my other scss files:

```
// styles/index.scss
@import './variables.scss';
@import './mixins.scss';
...

// container.scss
@import './styles/index.scss';
```

Comment: I will reference this variables.scss on all my components ? or that file will be automatic be referenced on each component?

Comment: Nice Masious, And the last question to finish this one.
Do you know if that import will be replicated for each component or it will be reduced once we go to deployment?

Comment: Sure yeah! you import the `index.scss` file in every file which wants to use these values, but when it transpiles, everything will be imported only once!
Besides, there is nothing left of the variable definitions in the css output!
P.S: A vote up would also be appreciated. :)